# ExpressJS redirect index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

JS,

I have an express app with some routes. When my router doesn't match any route it will display index.html instead of going to route '/*' and redirect to a specific route.

I don't understand why my router doesn't go to `app.get('/*')` because when I type `https://my-domain.com` I want to be redirect to `https://my-domain.com/test?id=1`.
Maybe I can do something with express-static but I don't know how.

And if I name my file `home.html` instead of `index.html` it's work perfectly.

Here is a small piece of my code :

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require('ejs');
const csrf = require('csurf');

const port = 3080;

let csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(csrfProtection);
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)

    res.status(403).json({error: "Invalid CSRF Token"});
})

app.post('/roles', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
    /*...*/
});

app.get('/test', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
    /*...*/
});


app.all('/*', csrfProtection, (req,res) => {
    if(Object.keys(req.query).length == 0) {
        res.redirect("https://my-domain.com/test?id=1");
    }
    res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'), {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on the port::${port}`);
});
```

My files structure is :

- home

  - static

    - css
    - js
  - index.html
  - index.js

Comment: I find a way to resolve my problem. I changed how my files and folders was organised and everything works now !

Answer (score 0):

At the request for `https://my-domain.com`, write `res.redirect('/foo/bar')`, where /foo/bar is the url you want to redirect to.

See Official Documentation For `res.redirect()`: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: I think it's not the problem. The script does not go to`app.all('/*')`. If i put a `console.log("debug");` nothing appear.